How to print name of third subdirectory of /home directory?
How to print name of (for example) third subdirectory of /home directory in Bash?
I have this from Chat GPT, but I am not sure about that.
ls -d /home/*/ | sed -n '3p' | xargs basename


What are you not sure about? Does it output a wrong answer?

Policy: Generative AI is banned

It will also include symbolic links that point to directories. Is that OK?

What's the point of asking ChatGPT when you have no way to evaluate its answer? And ChatGPT's reliability on technical questions is questionable, so you're right to not simply trust.

@JohnBollinger OTOH, this solution doesn't seem too bad.

How do you define which entry is third?

@JohnBollinger 3p

I am asking about your opinion. For example to add more simple solution. I have never worked with xargs basename before.

@david751 Do you know how xargs works in general? If so, what makes this particularly confusing?

The code can break in several ways.  If any of the subdirectory names contains a newline character then the sed command may print the wrong directory path, or a partial directory path.  If any of the subdirectory names contains whitespace or quote characters then xargs may pass multiple, possible garbled, arguments to basename.  Unfortunately, garbage code like this is very commonly seen, so it's not surprising that ChatGPT is parroting it.

One possible way to do what you want is set -- /home/*/; d=${3%/}; printf '%s\n' "${d##*/}".  That should work with any POSIX-compatible shell (including Bash and Dash).  It can handle all possible subdirectory names; including ones containing newlines, other whitespace characters, quotes, and globbing metacharacters.

ls -d1 "$HOME"/* | sed -n '3p' | cut -d'/' -f4

"Don't parse the output of ls" is one of the oldest, most well known FAQs in shell programming. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

@EdMorton It's not being captured and then output by another command. It's a direct pipeline.

@JayCravens it still won't work since directory names can contain newlines, for example.

@EdMorton That's a chance I'm willing to take, I guess.  I've encountered a file name containing a \n twice in 23 years.  Which leads me to ask... How are you going to parse any directory listing, at all, without using ls, dir or find?

I've been shell programming for 42 years and never used dir so I'm not sure what it's use is. find has no problem with newlines in file or directory names. I use ls all the time but just when running it manually to see some output. If I wanted to do anything else then I'd just use whatever is best suited for whatever that something else is. Using tools that output NUL chars instead of newlines at the end of file names is useful, e.g. printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 foo to call foo on each file in your directory. find, printf, stat, and xargs are the usual tools.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

No, I'm really not very interested in this age-old topic but if you have a question then please just ask it as a question.

@EdMorton for f in *; do echo "$f"; done  The site says that's # Good!  Okay, I'll play along... How do I make that show only/no directories?

@JayCravens please just ask that (or anything else) as a new question. I do think it's a good question, but having that discussion in the comments of some other question isn't in-line with why this site exists and it can be handled better in every way as it's own question. But I'd recommend the question to be phrased along the lines of "how do I do foo with the directories under my current directory" and pick a meaningful "foo" - no-one would ever do for f in *; do echo "$f"; done instead of just ls so asking how to make that show directories could get some unhelpful answers.

I know.  I've been trying to promote chat use.  You don't care to discuss it, I understand. It's not something I'm going to make a question for, I can figure it out.

The site exists to create a directory of questions/answers that future visitors can search to find answers to their questions so, even more so than discussions in comments about some other question than was asked, similar discussions in private chat sessions are contrary to that objective. I'm fine with discussing it but only if it's in the intended way for this site. It takes very little time to post a question but if you'd rather not post a question, that's fine too. All the best.

@EdMorton They are two entirely different creatures.  I'm going to ask lots of things about that, not just directories.  Using some q&a post format is nothing like a real time conversation, that will actually be discourse.  There is no parallel between a posting format and a real-time conversation. Something of this nature needs back and forth.  The next questions are highly dependent on the previous response.  This cannot even be achieved with a q&a.

Agreed, but that's not what this site is for. This site is for asking a question about a real, specific problem you've encountered and getting an answer to that question so it solves that problem. There are forums out there for general technical discussions, comp.unix.shell on Usenet, for example, is often used that way. Maybe google groups has some way of doing that too, idk. Good luck.

Why don't you collect all directories in your home into an array (in whatever order you want), and then pick the 3rd element of the array?


How to print name of (for example) third subdirectory of /home directory in Bash?

It depends on the order with respect to which you define "third".
It also depends on what exactly you want to print -- a full path, a basename, something else?
If you're satisfied with the order that a glob pattern produces, and if it's the basename you want to print, then I would do this:
( dirs=(/home/*/); basename "${dirs[2]}" )

That collects the names matching glob pattern /home/*/ in an array, then prints the basename of the third element.  It does this in a subshell to avoid conflict with any other variable named dirs, and to avoid leaving its definition of dirs in the host shell environment.
The output will in many cases be the same as that of the command suggested in the question, but it will be correct (relative to the specifications above) in some potential cases that the suggested one would get wrong.  In particular, if one of the first three directory names contains a newline or space or tab.
The above is also simpler, and IMO clearer, than the alternative suggested in the question.

What if there are fewer than 3 subdirectories?

Then it will print nothing, @Barmar, which is plausible.

Or POSIX-shell friendly: sh -c 'printf %s\\n "${3##*/}"' _ /home/* or without sub-shell quick and dirty set -- /home/*; printf %s\\n "${3##*/}".

Those don't do the job, @LéaGris, if in /home there is a regular file among the first three entries.  The question asks for the third subdirectory.

@JohnBollinger this one works even with files in-between: set -- /home/*/; d=${3%/}; [ -d "$d" ] && printf %s\\n "${d##*/}" or sh -c 'd=${3%/}; [ -d "$d" ] && printf %s\\n "${d##*/}"' _ /home/*/

Agreed, @LéaGris.  It does clobber the positional parameters, but that might be ok, depending on the circumstances.  Especially if you do it in a function, but in that case you could also just declare a local variable dirs to serve instead of a subshell.  I do think the set approach is worthy of mention, but I prefer the one in this answer, myself.
